# Kendo Grid & AngularJS - How to fill datagrid using async request in Angular version of the datagrid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to ask how to fill Angular Kendo data grid with async request.

Template:

```
        <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
        </kendo-grid>
```

Init:

```
$scope.test = [];

$scope.mainGridOptions = {
        //data: data.results,
        dataSource : {
            data : $scope.test,
            schema : {
                model : {
                    fields : {
                        name : {
                            type : "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize : 20,
        },
        sortable : true,
        height : 550,
        pageable : true,
        columns : [{
            field : "name",
            title : $translate.instant('NAME'),
            width : "120px"
        }]
    };



$scope.test = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport : {
                read : function(options) {
                    return $http.post('/api/getReportData/', {
                        sDate : '',
                        eDate : ''
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        options.success(data);
                    }).error(function() {
                        return;
                    })
                    console.log("mmm");
                }
             }
        });
```

`$scope.test` should be a remote request which returns the result to the grid.

How can I do it ? What's the best way to do it in an Angular way ?

Comment: You seem confused on how Kendo UI DataSource objects work. You shouldn't separate properties of the same DataSource across two objects (i.e. the `dataSource` definition in your grid and `$scope.test`). They belong together in the same DataSource definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think just a small change and you might have it.  In your grid definition you are creating the dataSource as a plain object, but setting data to $scope.test which is a kendo datasource.

I would move the schema definition stuff down to the dataSource ($scope.test) so that it looks like

```
$scope.test = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport : {
            read : function(options) {
                return $http.post('/api/getReportData/', {
                    sDate : '',
                    eDate : ''
                }).success(function(data) {
                    options.success(data);
                }).error(function() {
                    return;
                })
                console.log("mmm");
            }
         },
         schema : {
            model : {
                fields : {
                    name : {
                        type : "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize : 20,
    });
```

Then have your grid defintion

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource : $scope.test,
    sortable : true,
    height : 550,
    pageable : true,
    columns : [{
        field : "name",
        title : $translate.instant('NAME'),
        width : "120px"
    }]
};
```

I believe it will work.